# Why float taking 0.699999 instead of 0.7

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point, dev-c++

Here x is taking 0.699999 instead of 0.7 but y is taking 0.5 as assigned. Can you tell me what is the exact reason for this behavior.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
float x = 0.7;
float y = 0.5;
if (x < 0.7)
{
if (y < 0.5)
   cout<<"2 is right"<<endl;
else 
   cout<<"1 is right"<<endl;
}
else 
   cout<<"0 is right"<<endl; 

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has been asked so many times... Unfortunately, the value seems to always be different, so searching for dupes automatically is hard.

Comment: you should never compare floating point numbers strictly. Use a small tolerance for instance float eps = 1e-12; if (a < b - epsylon)`

Comment: `0.7` cannot be represented exactly in a `float` ([example](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046055)). `0.5` can ([example](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046053)).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://accu.org/index.php/articles/1558

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The amazing thing is that the code is almost the same...

Comment: Mongodb converts your float value to double so it loses it's precision. Declare your variable as double and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are lots of things on the internet about IEEE floating point.

```
0.5 = 1/2
```

so can be written exactly as a sum of powers of two

```
0.7 = 7/10 = 1/2 + 1/5 = 1/2 + 1/8 + a bit more... etc
```

The `bit more` can never be exactly a power of two, so you get the closest it can manage.

Answer (score 0):

floating point representation is approximate only as you cannot have precise representation of real, non-rational numbers on a computer.
`
when operating on floats, errros will in general accumulate.

however, there *are* some reals which can be represented exactly on a digital computer using it's native datatype for this purpose (*), 0.5 being one of them.

(*) meaning the format the floating point processing unit of the cpu operates on (standardized in ieee754). specialized libraries can represent integer and rational numbers exactly beyond the limits of the processor's internal formats. rounding errors may still occur when converting into a human-readable decimal expansion and the alternative also does not extend to irrational numbers (e.g. sqrt(3)). and, of course, these libraries comes at the cost of less speed.

Answer (score 0):

It is to do with how floating points are represented in memory. They have a limited number of bits (usually 32 for a `float`). This means there are a limited number of values that can be represented which means that many numbers from the infinite set of real numbers cannot be represented.

[This website explains further](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand exactly why, then have a look at floating point representation of your machine (most probably it's IEEE 754, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point ).

If you want to write robust and portable code, never compare floating-point values for equality. You should always compare them with some precision  (e.g. instead of `x==y` you should write `fabs(x-y) < eps` where `eps` is say `1e-6`).