# MongoDb saving different value for the float numbers

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I am trying to insert a document having a geocoordinate key with value [77.218624, 28.635101] but when I insert in mongodb from the shell I get this value in the database [ 
                    77.21862400000001, 
                    28.635101
                ], 
Can anybody tell why this number is being changed after inserting into mongoDb

Comment: Because it isn't exactly representable. There are lots of answers about floating point here. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612654/why-float-taking-0-699999-instead-of-0-7

Comment: But for a geocoordinate if the values changes it meaning and location will change with a very high difference.